# How to solve jquery Twice script execution with dialogs?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a dialog (`$('.dialog').show()`), that writes a form (`$.post('/form/xyz', null, function (data) { $('.dialog').html( data );} )`). That form has an script (javascript/jquery) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myform/script.js">
<form>
   <input type="text" value="click me!" id="clickme" />
</form>
```

The script has the following code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$(document).on('click','#clickme', function () { alert('you clicked me'); } );
});
```

The problem is: each time the dialog is showed I need to re-execute the script but when I click `#clickme` I get the alert showed the times that the script was executed.

I never noted this problem (I don't know why) but now that is happening. I'm working with jQuery 1.9.2, and I'm thinking to use the function (`preventPropagation`), but I think this isn't reliable because I should need to do this at each 'on' event. In addition, I believed that doing an **'script loading history'** will solve the problem to control that, but I have the problem that when I need to execute functions when the form is loaded I will cannot re-execute automatically as well as I'm doing now.

What's the solution?

Full example:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#open-dialog').on('click', function () {
  $.post( '/server-form.php', null, function (data) {
     $('.dialog').html( data );
  });
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dialog">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Open dialog" id="open-dialog"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP** (server-form.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dynamic-script/30a2f63d6276a21db19782b2d8c93363.js">
    <form>
       <input type="text" value="click me!" id="clickme" />
    </form>
```

**DYNAMIC-SCRIPT dynamic-script/30a2f63d6276a21db19782b2d8c93363.js **

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$(document).on('click','#clickme', function () { alert('you clicked me'); } );
});
```

That's all!!!

Comment: Would be easier for answerers if you provided a complete html/javascript snippet instead of pieces.

Comment: I don't get it, is click handler declared inside "myform/script.js" or what?

Comment: yes it is, and the script is executed each time the dialog is showed, look at the full example. You will understand why

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$(document).ready(){
   $("#clickme").click(function(){
       alert("you've clicked me!");
   })
}
```

Comment: how about: $("#clickme").on(...) ?

Comment: Hey!! it works!! .. but now I don't understand why??? what's the difference $(document).on('clickme') and $(clickme).on ??

Comment: $(document).on (..) mean you bind the event handler to the document object, so everything you click will do the alert script :D. $("#click").on mean you bind the event handler to the #click only. Pretty simple right? :D